# Show contacts deatils in pageblocksection as selected in picklist

Tags: pageblock

I have List of all contacts in picklist field on visualforce page.
Below that field i have a pageblock section giving details of contact.
I want to show only the details of the field as selected in picklist
eg. I have 3 contacts in dropdown abc, pqr and xyz. When i select ABC i should be able to see First name and Last name of ABC in Pageblock section. This fo same for pqr and xyz

Comment: Are these contacts related to some parent record like Account or Case? Do you already have the VF page? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi Peter, This contacts are related to a parent record Account.I have a standard controller Account with extension. I have got all the related contacts in picklist and have apageblock section below to display relevant contact details.... my code always shows me the first contact...the section is rendered again on change but same contact details are shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Use select list with action support and one controller method that loads contact details:

Page:

```
<apex:actionRegion>
<apex:selectList value="{!selectedContact}" size="1" multiselect="false">
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="ID1XXXXXXX" itemLabel="Contact1"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="ID2XXXXXXX" itemLabel="Contact2"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="ID3XXXXXXX" itemLabel="Contact3"/>
    <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" 
                        action="{!loadDetails}" 
                        rerender="contactDetails"/>
</apex:selectList> 
</apex:actionRegion>

<apex:pageBlockSection title="Details" columns="1" id="contactDetails">
    <apex:outputField value="{!con.firstname}"/>
    <apex:outputField value="{!con.lastname}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Controller:

```
public Contact con { get; set; }
public String selectedContact { get; set; }

public PageReference loadDetails(){
    con = [Select LastName, FirstName From Contact Where Id = :selectedContact ];
    return null;
}
```

Comment: @Test It's cool!  :)